# Styling a material table to match a design

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have been given the following design:
[image]

I have a material table put together displaying the needed information. I however have been unable to style this in a way that matches the design.

```
    <mat-table
  multiTemplateDataRows
  [dataSource]="imagesData"
  class="material-images">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Image">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="imageSelected(element.id)" [attr.rowspan]="3">
      <img src="{{element.url}}" alt="No image found" class="image" style="height: 10rem">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Title">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <h4 class="leadingLabel">Title: </h4>
      <p class="leadingLabel">{{element.title || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Time">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <h4>Time: </h4>
      <p>{{element.timestamp || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Created By">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <h4 class="leadingLabel">Created By: </h4>
      <p class="leadingLabel">{{element.createdBy || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Output">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <h4>Output: </h4>
      <p>{{element.output || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <h4 class="leadingLabel">Description: </h4>
      <p class="leadingLabel">{{element.description || 'None'}}</p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['Image','Title', 'Time'];"></mat-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['Created By', 'Output'];"></mat-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['Description'];"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Are there any CSS gurus that would be able to help me out? I honestly don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a different class to your elements.

Did you try something like: .leadingLabel{color:red;} in your css styles (style.css).

or

```
<style>
.leadingLabel{color:red;}
</style>
```

Sorry, if I don't understand your question !

Comment: I am more looking for the correct layout rules to achieve the design given